# Calculating Mersenne numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

We have the task to build a simple recursive function displaying the [*Mersenne number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) in Haskell, sorted from smallest to biggest number.
It's basicly 2^n-1
So `mersenne 7` looks something like that `[0,1,3, 7, 15, 31, 63]`

We couldn't get it done sadly and are stuck on that piece of code.

```
mrs :: Integer -> [Integer]
mrs 1 = [0]
mrs n = n : mrs (2^(n-1)-1)
```

But somehow the numbers are increasing in size while they should decrease because n is getting lower. I believe it's easy to solve and I'll feel dumb afterwards, but so be it.

Currently, for input `7` it spits out `[7, 63, 46.........giant number, error]`

For input `3` it constantly spits out `3`'s: `[3,3,3,3...]` and lower than that tells me about negativ exponents.

We are quite new to Haskell, all googling and reading through scripts didn't work.

Comment: You're increasing your n number every time, not decreasing it. `2^(n-1)-1` is the new `n` value you pass in to the function at each call.

Comment: The numbers are not decreasing, you're calling mrs with 2^(n-1)-1. It looks like you inversed the number to put in the list and the number to compute

Comment: Step back and ask yourself what does `n` represent when you call `mrs n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to decrease your `n` value with each call, but you're currently increasing it. What you really want is probably:

```
mrs :: Integer -> [Integer]
mrs 1 = [0]
mrs n = (2^(n-1)-1) : mrs (n-1)

> mrs 7
[63,31,15,7,3,1,0]
```

If you want to keep the order increasing, just reverse the list:

```
> reverse $ mrs 7
[0,1,3,7,15,31,63]
```

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding a guard that `n > 1`, otherwise `mrs 0` will result in an infinite list.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Fair point. I thought the Mersenne numbers were defined only for positive `n`, but it does leave a dangerous function without that protection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew I was off  "a bit". Now I think about it, it's really straight forward. First element in the list is my statement, the tail will be recursive -1 untill I reach 1. Still getting used to the syntax.

Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more declarative style to do this is probably defining a range `[1..n]` and then perform a mapping over it: `\x -> 2^(x-1)-1`:

```
mrs n = map (\x -> 2^(x-1)-1) [1..n]
```

or a pointfree approach:

```
mrs n = map (subtract 1 . (2 ^) . subtract 1) [1..n]
```

Now we can improve the situation by performing the `subtract 1` already in the range:

```
mrs n = map (subtract 1 . (2 ^)) [0..n-1]
```

This produces:

```
Prelude> mrs 7
[0,1,3,7,15,31,63]
```

Comment: The original question already wants them in *increasing* order